# Display a part of web page using iframe div

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe

Hi  I want to iframe  target and  display only product images

div.a-text-center.a-fixed-left-grid-col

from this page

amazon.com/dp/B07B8K64VY/

is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible without JavaScript XHR or Web Scraping because you can't use custom CSS in iframe.